# Error 65537 while instatiating the CBC mode

Tags: python, encryption, aes, pycryptodome

I have been using the `PyCryptoDome` library to encrypt some communications between a client and a server. Here is how the protocol goes.

1. The server sends an RSA public key to the client.
2. The client generates an AES key
3. The client encrypts it. encrypts it using the public key (with the `PKCS1_OAEP` encrypt function)
4. The encrypted key is sent to the server.
5. The server decrypts the key
6. The server and client switch to AES-CBC to encrypt communications.

After that, when the client sends a message, the server decrypts it, uses it for what needs to be done with it, and then sends it back. All goes well until the client tries to decrypt the message that is sent back by the server. The thread for receiving messages stops, due to:

> Error 65537 while instatiating the CBC mode

Different error codes happen when using different AES modes.

Here is my modified `AESCipher` Class:

```
import binascii
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES


class AESCipher(object):

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.pad = lambda s: s + (AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size) * \
            chr(AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size)
        self.unpad = lambda s: s[:-ord(s[len(s) - 1:])]

    def encrypt(self, raw):
        iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return binascii.b2a_hex(iv + cipher.encrypt(self.pad(raw)))

    def decrypt(self, enc):
        enc = binascii.a2b_hex(enc)
        iv = enc[:AES.block_size]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return self.unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[AES.block_size:]))
```

Client receiving side (the error-causing side):

```
def recvMesgThread(netcat, output, aescipher):
    while True:
        try:
            data = netcat.recv_until('\r\n').replace('\r\n', '')
        except NetcatError:
            print('Lost connection to server!')
            sys.exit(0)

        if data[:5] == '/MESG' and data[-5:] =='MESG/' :
            try:
                output.append(aescipher.decrypt(buf[5:-5]))
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

Comment: What happens if you use the `AESCipher` directly, without using client / server?

Comment: Separate note: your protocol is entirely flawed; use TLS 1.2. There is trust in the public key, no authentication of messages and you're vulnerable to padding oracle attacks, to name just some issues.

Comment: Using AESCipher directly to encrypt and decrypt a string multiple times showed no such error. I know that this is insecure, I will soon switch to Diffie-Hellman to exchange an AES-EAX key.

Comment: OK, so we have provided code that works, which happens to error when used with code that messes up the input? Is that correct?

Comment: Okay, will provide the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing...

The problem was a typo. Line 11 tries to decrypt the `buf` variable, which doesn't exist. The `data` variable was the one that contained what I needed.